# Aspose.Pdf.Document.Save() throws an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' when used with a MemoryStream

Tags: .net-6.0, asp.net-core-3.1, memorystream, aspose

We are trying to save a PDF document using the Aspose.Pdf.Document.Save() method. Our code worked when run as .netcore3.1 but we have upgraded to .NET6 and it is now failing.  Our Aspose version has not changed, so I am assuming the error comes from the c# /.NET end of things.

When we attempt to save we are getting the following exception:

```
memoryStream.ReadTimeout = 'finalStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type
 System.InvalidOperationException'
 The memoryStream stream is a MemoryStream, and MemoryStreams do not support timeouts.
```

We have tried the following to fix the error:

- Setting the ReadTimeout property of the memoryStream stream.
- Using the Aspose.Pdf.Document.Export() method instead of the Aspose.Pdf.Document.Save() method.
- using 'flush()' and 'stream.Position = 0;'

**Reproducible example:**

The following code is reproducible:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var pdfDoc = new Aspose.Pdf.Document()) 
{ 
….
}
pdfDoc.Save(memoryStream);
```

Comment: Instead of using Aspose.PDF, please try using Aspose.Pdf.Drawing as it is published for .NET 6.0 like environments. Furthermore, we have also noticed your similar inquiry (https://forum.aspose.com/t/convert-htmlstring-to-pdf-using-net-core-6-and-aspose-pdf-version-23-8-0-null-reference-exception/271275) in our forum where we have responded you. You may please follow up there. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Asad Ali, thank you for the reply.  We will try the Aspose.Pdf.Drawing.  Note however that I am not associated at all with the person who submitted the issue on the Aspose forum.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this issue on our own.  Solution was to upgrade Aspose.  We had been running at version 21.2.  This older version was kept in our build because of some breaking changes introduced in latter versions (removing the 360 degree rotate option).  To get our Memory Stream issue solved we first tried to upgrade to the current version, 23.9, but then got the error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I then lowered the version incrementally until this package mismatch disappeared at 23.4.

Although this now fixes our Memory Stream issue we will have to go back and rewrite the code which breaks when upgrading from 21.2->23.4.